# Nuget: All packages give "Failed to generate binding redirects for 'ProjectName'. An item with the same key has already been added."

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I created a solution with some Class Library and ASP.NET MVC projects and added some references with Nuget. Everything went ok, but the next day, when running "update-package" from the Package Manager Console, I started getting this warning for all packages for all projects:

> Failed to generate binding redirects for 'ProjectName'. An item with the
>   same key has already been added.

The thing is that all binding redirects seem to be there and pointing to the latest version of the libraries, they even seem to be updating correctly when packages update. Also, all code compiles and runs correctly.

This message is showing for any package, even packages that don't use binding redirects like javascript libraries and typescript definitions.

I'd like to know if there is a way to debug this warnings and find out why they are happening.

I'm using VS 2013 all up to date, with nuget 2.7.3/2.7.41115.310.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. I solved it by removing the reference connection between the projects. I then updated and installed the packages I needed. After I added the reference to the class library again and everything was fine.